# jQuery .menu() not automatically creating submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, menu, submenu

I am trying to create a menu formated by jQuery. The appearance and functionality of level one items is correct, but the subsquent levels are not correctly formatting as a submenu that appears with mouse over. Rather it simply appears, and does not highlight the items as the level one items do with mouse over or hover (neither function appears in my code).

**HTML CODE**

```
    <div style="width: 25%">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**jQuery or JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').menu({menus: "div"});
});
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mherPresident/526Q9/)

Comment: are you talking jqueryui menu or some js plugin menu ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is a matter of simply deleting in the JavaScript the following from line 6:

```
{menus: div}
```

Comment: Line 6 corresponds to my personal JS file, it is the second line in the code given in the question

Comment: so you are going for default behavior then why did you use menus option ?

Comment: I did that because I read that in the documentation when learning how to use menu()

Comment: yeah but always go for default option first..which has most of the things. if that doesn't look good, then we should go looking for options